# Why is ValueChanges fired on init when nothing changed?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a popup component in which I have mat-datepicker, when user changes the date I want to patch this value to another control and make `start` and `end` controls valid (because of the mat-date-range-input bug, nevermind). The problem is that when I open datepicker for the third/fourth time I get the **NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked** error because ValueChanges is called even if I don't change anything yet. How to do this?

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.range.get('start').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.updateFormattedDates();
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });

    this.range.get('end').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.updateFormattedDates();
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }

updateFormattedDates() {
...
}
```

Comment: You're calling `detectChanges` inside of `valueChanges`, which is triggered by `detectChanges`. Sounds like a recipe for a lot of changes being reported. What you do in `updateFormattedDates` matters too, especially if it modifies `start` or `end`. Please do provide a [mre] of the issue so that people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use rxjs [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged) to reduce the number of events, also there is no need for `detectChanges()` maybe that is the cause for the warning message!

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.range.get('start')?.valueChanges.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.updateFormattedDates();
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });

    this.range.get('end')?.valueChanges.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.updateFormattedDates();
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-18grsk?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: okay using this I got rid of this error but it doesn't solve my problem, I mea in this updateFormattedDates I have .setErrors(null) functions and now it doesn't update errors

Comment: @cherryBom please see from my side, no code is shared to fix it, please share back the  stackblitz with the issue replicated only then I can debug!